# Exploding a number and separate it by a space

Tags: php, string

I want to explode a string or an integer and separate it by a space.

E.g., I have this int **12345678**, and I want its numbers to become like **123 45678**. I want the first three numbers separated. Can someone give me a clue or hint in how to achieve this, like what function to use in PHP? I think using an `explode` will not work here because the `explode` function needs a separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) :

```
$str = "12345678" ;
echo substr($str,0,3)." ".substr($str, 3); // "123 45678"
```

Also works with an integer :

```
$int = 12345678 ;
echo substr($int,0,3)." ".substr($int, 3); // "123 45678"
```

Comment: I understand the first `substr` `0` means the start and `3` means the length. But how about the second?  why that method only have one parameter?

Comment: @nethkennnnn The second starts at 3 and get value until the end (no argument).

Comment: One more question @Syscall. How do we count it? Is the count same as an `array` like it starts with `0`. Or the `"` is counted as an element inside it?

Comment: @nethkennnnn Yes, indices starts with 0.

Comment: @nethkennnnn For start, length using 1, 2, 3...

Answer (score 5):

You can use [substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) - Replace text within a portion of a string.

```
echo substr_replace(1234567, " ", 3, 0); // 123 4567
```

https://3v4l.org/9CFlX

Comment: A better solution then the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will solve by using `substr()`.

The `substr()` function returns a part of a string.

Syntax: `substr(string,start,length)`

Example:

```
$value = "12345678";
echo substr($value,0,3)." ".substr($value, 3);

Output: 123 45678
```

You may get better understand from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp).

Comment: How does this differ from @Syscall answer?

Comment: The comment is quite similar to @syscall's comment. Now I try to add some description for better understand.